# Can not open file using fullpath in java

Tags: java, file

Here is the code I have now:

```
File file= new File("C:\Documents and Settings\vasanth\Desktop\s.PNG");
BufferedImage image;

try {
    image = ImageIO.read(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Raster raster = image.getRaster();

BufferedImage image2 = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
WritableRaster raster2 = image2.getRaster();
BufferedImage image3 = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
WritableRaster raster3 = image3.getRaster();
```

Should I keep the image that I am using here? Even though I have specified the full path to the image file, I still get an error.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Help us help you: post the error so we don't have to guess as to what it says.

Comment: You should add the error message you are getting (ideally the complete stack trace)

Comment: If you use Java 7, consider using `Files`.

Comment: also try not to always use absolute directories because then it will not work on other computers...

Answer (score 14):

Use double slash in java strings. Single slash is considered a character escape sequence.

So you should open the file like so:

```
File file= new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\vasanth\\Desktop\\s.PNG");
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with what Ivaylo said, have a look at this portion of code:

```
BufferedImage image;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Raster raster = image.getRaster();
```

Have you considered what happens if you have an exception assigning `image`? You will call a method on a null object and that will kill your app entirely with a `NullPointerException`.

You need to stop whatever you wanted to do with the image if an exception occurs. You can put all of it within the `try...catch` block to fix this.

Comment: With the code as it is, he will not get a `NullPointerException` - in fact, the code won't even compile, with an error "variable `image` might not have been initialized". (Local variables must be initialized explicitly; only member variables are by default initialized to `null`).